# What argument does spin_lock_init take?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to initialize at run time the `spin_lock` using the `spin_lock_init` function, but don't know what argument it takes, I saw from the docs that it takes a pointer to `spinlock_t` type but I don't know how to implement it. How can we *init* spinlock at run time using that function?

```c
int __init(void)
{
    spinlock_t my_lock; // spin lock type
    spin_lock_init(&my_lock); // void
    
    return 64;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. Spinlocks are implemented in Linux kernel and being represented by a type `spinlock_t` with an API `spin_lock_*()`. The above code looks correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage is correct. The `spin_lock_init()` function is intended to be used when you need to initialize a spinlock *at run time*. What is odd in your example is the fact that you are defining the spinlock inside a function: what purpose will that spinlock ever have if it's only defined there and gets discarded immediately when the function returns? You usually want to be able to lock/unlock it from different functions (or different calls of the same function).

Therefore, you usually want to have spinlocks as global variables, something like:

```c
static spinlock_t my_lock;

int __init myinit(void)
{
    spin_lock_init(&my_lock);
    return 0;
}
```

For usages in which you do not need to initialize the spinlock at runtime (because you already know that you will need it initialized right away), you can use the `DEFINE_SPINLOCK()` macro, that will both declare and initialize it for you at compile time, saving time and code:

```c
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(my_lock);
```

Comment: Another common instance of `spinlock_t` is as members of `struct` types, instances of which are often allocated dynamically.